# Creating Records/Objects of Classes w/ Different Generic Types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm curious if there are ways to define a `Record<string, {Class}>` that must conform to a type, except for the generics in the class (or, the more likely solution, if there is a concept besides `Record` that would be better-suited for this).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiB2ATADgewJbwC4B4BKApgI4CuBEWAKgJ7IEA00hEa8EBNdAfNAN4BQ0aMhIAjEOmDQAtmADWBQqXJYAFACdiALibEyFTgQCUO5q3aGBQocFRtUIAgDoQqAOYbiRwdc1YS6vB8AL7QkLosdha0BD7B-PH8tmxY0ARIaJhYEKYEtuqIOBTqmG6MCCgY2Dgk8HLwqADu8Iy19U3wXDwAvHw%20rm6YOvAEjXAZVbi8JOyBYNIEOsWljMiQEI2oBUtYJfBuwYy8ECTAwOQ50KKoDgRgLdBYqArwO3sHXKreickUaRNZCAAOVQCAAZltzgtsNBelZoAMhtARmMKplqtNZvB5otoMt9qt1pttnjdqVDnwTmcLjprrd7owni83uTPkZ6D4ABZNAgANwI6h0ACIsJyBQRoOgYA1-hD1FD0qk7I8YjAxZpGBBUI8xdQwpp4AByVJgEAgaCoME6iVoybQUDrIUJfj8AD0rugAHV0KLdPlCviyuNKlkanUGs1WuGOlwtC7fqlNJE2BLeukQ9gIC53JgnLIFEp9Gp4QsoGA3LihZROVLJTAsDFoG0I0FEGRHtrRRLCP6VXRoJywLzSk3o5GriQTTAfYaYNnBkEAJKGxAI9AKSWpJ4Im5yMJbsV8GYC7ELFkE4REraIc8HPvOJ3Bby-W7zzzJ9hGaDu0ftZoul0f29X0ZQbftEAIMFMAIVd7lXLt72gRBqFPSRTRAPVMDBAVNBveMokTchzAIAAmWF-gzbIQXBSECGhLB51zfNFD0FRVCsY85jPaAqxracYHyTRgCwIUOUvKBiRvHjwi7TQ62RbUe2vMIkAU38W3vJxH2fKJXwGd9iJIr8f2OU5zigWkbkcBkO2ZUl3mCIA)

What I'm trying to do in that example is define an object that must conform to `Record<string, Endpoint>`, but Endpoint has two generic types (for the request and response). I'd like for it to be impossible to create non-endpoint-class values in that object.

When flattening it into a `Record`, I'm forced to define the generics as `unknown`, however they are set specifically for each Endpoint.

What would be your way of architecting this? I'd like to avoid declaring them all as separate variables, but I also need to more strictly type these requests/responses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a generic function, you can avoid using unknown and still have type restrictions:

```
class Endpoint<RequestType, ResponseType> {
  public makeRequest(req: RequestType): ResponseType {
    console.log(req)
    return {} as ResponseType
  }
}

function createLoginEndpoint<RequestType, ResponseType>() {
  return { login: new Endpoint<RequestType, ResponseType>() }
}

let endpoints = createLoginEndpoint<{ username: string, password: string }, { success: boolean, token: string }>()

const response = endpoints.login.makeRequest({
  username: "Some_UserName",
  password: "Some_Password"
})
console.log(response)
```